# Convert a 16-bit integer to an array of char? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion

I need to write 16-bit integers to a file. fstream only writes characters. Thus I need to convert the integers to char - the actual integer, not the character representing the integer (i.e. 0 should be 0x00, not 0x30) I tried the following:

```
char * chararray = (char*)(&the_int);
```

However this creates a *backwards* array of two characters. The individual characters are not flipped, but the order of the characters is. Thus I created this function:

```
   char * inttochar(uint16_t input)
{
    int input_size = sizeof(input);
    char * chararray = (char*)(&input);
    char * output;
    output[0]='\0';
    for (int i=0; i<input_size; i++)
    {
        output[i]=chararray[input_size-(i+1)];
    }
    return output;
}
```

This seems slow. Surely there is a more efficient, less hacky way to convert it?

Comment: You can simply do `f << i` where `f` is your `ofstream` and `i` is your integer. If you want hex than you can do `f << "0x" << std::hex << i`.

Comment: I need to convert it to the the actual integer, not the character representing the integer. That method will turn an integer into the character representing the integer.

Comment: Voted as off-topic because it's too trivial, a non-problem.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The OP wants to write binary, big-endian (or to be precise, the endianness opposite of that native to their machine). Your proposal would produce text.

Comment: Your proposed function exhibits undefined behavior - it writes through `output` pointer that is never initialized.

Comment: That is true. However I know of no other way to do this, which is why I ask - I don't think my solution is a good one.

Comment: `char ch = the_int / 256; stream.write(&ch, 1); ch = the_int % 256; stream.write(&ch, 1);` This would guarantee big-endian order on any machine. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @Nick: if it's really endianness converison  you're after, then check out the posix functions https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Byte-Order.html

Comment: A bit more compact: `char arr[2] = {the_int / 256, the_int % 256}; stream.write(arr, 2);`

Comment: The problem is, it's not the chars in the array that are backwards - it's that the array itself is backwards. i.e. the first char in the array should be the last one, the last one should be the first one.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. Your solution works perfectly, I misunderstood. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to understand what you're asking here (perhaps it's just me, although I gather the commentators thought so too).

You write

> fstream only writes characters

That's true, but doesn't necessarily mean you need to create a character array explicitly.

E.g., if you have an `fstream` object `f` (opened in binary mode), you can use the [`write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) method:

```
uint16_t s;
...
f.write(static_cast<const char *>(&s), sizeof(uint16_t));
```

As others have noted, when you serialize numbers, it often pays to use a commonly-accepted ordering. Hence, use [`htons`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) (refer to the documentation for your OS's library):

```
uint16_t s;
...
const uint16_t ns = htons(s);
f.write(static_cast<const char *>(&ns), sizeof(uint16_t));
```

Comment: Oh, by the way - in case anyone else has this problem - I don't think the static cast there works (it doesn't for me at least.) Maybe it should be changed to reinterpret_cast or just (char*)(&ns)?